# Overlapping line with a textbox

Tags: windows, gdi+

I have an arrow with text associated with it. The text overlaps the arrow at certain point. I want the arrow to not visible in the rectangle that is bounded by the text i wrote the following code

```
  AdjustableArrowCap *cap1 = new AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5, true);
    Pen *myPen1 = new Pen(Color::Color(0,255,255), width);

    myPen->SetCustomEndCap(cap1);
    GraphicsPath path;
    path.AddLine(point1,point2);
     Font font(&FontFamily(L"arial"), 21);
     Brush *brush=new SolidBrush(Color::Color(0,255,255,255));

     SolidBrush solidBrush(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));

     StringFormat format;
     format.SetAlignment(StringAlignmentCenter);
     format.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignmentCenter);
     RectF rectbo;
     graph->MeasureString(strdata,wcslen(strdata),&font,PointF::PointF(point2),&rectbo);


    graph->DrawLine(myPen,point2,point1);
    Region pathRegion(&path);
    sta=pathRegion.Intersect(rectbo);
    graph->fillRegion(pathRegion,&brush);
    graph->DrawString(strdata,wcslen(strdata),&font,point2,&format,brush1);
  }
```

I feel like i m trying to fill up a line with colour which is not possible so how can i make the line invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing the line from the Point2 calculate which corner point or centered edge point (Depending on your design preference) is closest to Point1 then draw the line from there.